# Angular FlexLayout make image use the leftover space

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

We have got an Angular app with FlexLayout. The design is that the left 50% container contains "some stuff" and in the right 50% container we want to display an explainatory text at the bottom and above the text, we want to display an image. This is a stripped down version to explain the issue.

```
<div fxLayout="row" style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid green">
  <div fxFlex="50" style="border: 1px solid red"></div>
  <div fxFlex="50" style="border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; padding: 1rem" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
    <div fxFlex style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border: 1px solid blue">
      <img src="assets/images/demo.svg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
      erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
      est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
      labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
      gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
      nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
      sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
      accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
      diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
      sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we remove the <img ... /> it will do exactly what it is supposed to do, but as soon as we add the img, the div around the image will be resized to fit its content, but we want the img to adapt to its container.

I also created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-5mfy22?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) with editable text and show hide image button to play around.

Comment: Try adding `style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;"` to your <img> tag

Comment: Angular's [Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) library is deprecated now. Check [this blog](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127) for more.

Comment: @stax that does not change it.

Comment: @msrumon that is not helpful as the customer still makes us use it.

Comment: @Woozar Can you please provide an working stackblitz example so i can look into it in detail.

Comment: @stax I never used it, but I will try.

Comment: @stax please take a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-5mfy22?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Woozar i added exactly the same code as i commented before to the image tag and i think it looks like what it should ... [here](https://www.screenpresso.com/de/cloud/miIU/).
Or what was your expected result?

Comment: @stax ok, this is super weired. On stackblitz it works but on my local dev system it does not :(

Comment: @stax too much different version with different behavior. My version on stackblitz is not working. i would expect it would scale down the image instead of cutting off the text and the end of the page. https://imgur.com/cTsU8Ju

Comment: Heres a forked version of your stackblitz workspace with the changes i made. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-7rvmje?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the container element and `width: 100%` to the image.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/angular-flexlayout-make-image-use-the-leftover-space-tx6qs7)

---

I'm trying to achieve this for the past hour, and seems like something is off with "Flex Layout" library. Hence, I'm sharing my way to achieve this without that library.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.child1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.child1--left {
  border: 4px solid lime;
}

.child1--right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.child2__image {
  min-height: 0; /* IMPORTANT */
  border: 3px solid indigo;
}

.child2__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1 child1--left"></div>
  <div class="child1 child1--right">
    <div class="child2__image">
      <img src="https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/1801287.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="child2__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam voluptatum voluptate id veniam earum explicabo optio nulla saepe ipsum obcaecati consequatur, hic ratione quam fugit porro iusto quia, exercitationem, sapiente animi dolore neque voluptates culpa amet. Iste dolorum nulla delectus officiis libero, sunt illo consequuntur, nihil totam sit facilis obcaecati!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **The end result matters more that the tool(s) you use to achieve a certain goal.**

Feel free to leave your opinion.

Comment: I want to it shrink the image so everything fits on one page. In your example there is a scrollbar on the right (on my screen)

Comment: Add `height: 100vh` to the "green-bordered" element.

Comment: then it cuts off the text instead of shrinking the image

Comment: Hi, you may wanna check my updated answer.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks for the effort. I will need a little time to check your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` `height: 100%;` `object-fit: contain;` to the image tag.

Heres the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-7rvmje?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: the text at the bottom is still being cut off see [here](https://imgur.com/a/LqyEjk8)

Comment: At some certain screen size it isn't possible to display all of that text, so i would just enable a scrollbar ... just add `overflow: auto` to your div element that contains the text.

Comment: That is true in theory, but our customer runs the app on own hardware, that guarantees, that a minimum resolution is kept and with that resolution it will not be an issue and he will not accept scrollbars here